# In a templated class, how do I define a function with a different typename

Tags: c++, templates, g++

**EDIT:** This is **NOT** a duplicate of the standard templating questions.

My scenario involves a templated class and a member function of that class whith one argument that is templated, but not of the same type as the class.

Even when I put the definition in the header I still can't find the correct syntax.

Can someone help me with my specific question?

---

My oversimplified code:

Foo.h:

```
template<typename T1>
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename T2>
    static void bar(vector<T1>& a, vector<T2>& b);
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include <Foo.h>

template<typename T1>
template<typename T2>
void Foo<T1>::bar(vector<T1>& a, vector<T2>& b) {
    //code logic
}
```

Goo.cpp:

```
#include <Foo.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> a;
    vector<double> b;
    Foo<int>::bar(a, b);
}
```

---

My error:

```
undefined reference to
void Foo<int>::bar<double>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, 
std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)
```

---

I couldn't find the proper way to define the templates.

I also noticed that the order of the typenames will change the error (also putting the entire function in the class declaration).

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Why do you think this is not a duplicate? You cant define templates in the source file. "Even when I put the definition in the header I still can't find the correct syntax." ...then why dont you show the code with the definition in the header?

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us the code with the templated member function defined in the header file, we can reopen it.  Kudos for simplifying your code - do make sure the edited simplified version still fails, and include the error message. (If you @-mention me in a comment, I think I can reopen it single handedly.)

Comment: Your Foo.h has a typo and a missing semicolon. Please only copy and paste code you have actually tried to compile and verified that you get the claimed error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the declarations or definitions. The problem is the splitting of definition and declaration. That doesn't work the way you are doing it.  When compiling `foo.cpp`, no uses of your template are visible, and so there will be no instances created.  When compiling `goo.cpp`, the linker will therefore not be able to link to them.

Thats what this error means:

> undefined reference to 'void Foo<int>::bar<double>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)'

If you really want to do what you are doing, you need to use explicit instantiation for every combination of types.

Change `foo.cpp` to this (note the explicit instantiation definition in the last line):

```
template<typename T1>
template<typename T2>
void Foo<T1>::bar(std::vector<T1>& a, std::vector<T2>& b) {
    //code logic
}

template void Foo<int>::bar(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<double>&);
```